# Why i get the connection string error when connect the oracle DB with c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to connect the oracle function and read any data from it,and i'm write this code for that purpose:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=WEBSERVICE_ACCESS;User Id=webservice_access;Password=xyz;"))
{
     con.Open();
     OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LOGIN");
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     //Add your parameters here
     cmd.Connection = con;
     OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (odr.Read())
     {
          Console.WriteLine(odr.GetOracleValue(0));
     }
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

> WEBSERVICE_ACCESS is my DATABASE NAME
>   
>   webservice_access is my user name
>   
>   but when run that code i get this error:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

What happened? How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Your connection string is wrong. Either that or the server is setup wrong. It is hard to diagnose any more without looking at your systems.

Comment: Also, I hope the password in your connection string is not the real one :-)

Comment: @RuneGrimstad I update my question,please review that.thanks

Comment: Is `WEBSERVICE_ACCESS` the name in your tnsnames?

Comment: @PatrickHofman WEBSERVICE_ACCESS is my Database name

Comment: `WEBSERVICE_ACCESS` should be the name of an entry of `tnsnames.ora`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error ORA-12514 means that a listener received a request to
>   establish a connection to a database or other service. The connect
>   descriptor received by the listener specified a service name for a
>   service (usually a database service) that either has not yet
>   dynamically registered with the listener or has not been statically
>   configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition such as
>   after the listener has started, but before the database instance has
>   registered with the listener.

The possible resolutions for this error are

Check which services are currently known by the listener by    executing:  Hide   Copy Code

```
lsnrctl services <listener name>
```

1) Check that the SERVICE_NAME parameter in the connect descriptor of    the net service name used specifies a service known by the listener. 
2) If an easy connect naming connect identifier was used, check that the  service name specified is a service known by the listener.
3)Check for    an event in the listener.log file

This [answer](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm) on oracle forums should help you understand the difference between the SID and the SERVICE_NAME.